# Can we *please* have an exception to the 6-character minimum edit for "it's"?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I am at least half serious about this--"its"/"it's" confusion bugs me that much, and I know I'm not alone.  Please, *please* let me improve the quality of questions and answers in this way.  Often the single best change to a question or answer is the removal of an apostrophe, because it allows, we'll say, a certain subset of people to focus on the rest of the post rather than be stirred up to a frothy rage.

Pretty please?

Comment: If there is that issue wouldn't there most likely be other issues that need fixing?

Comment: I see a *lot* of posts that are otherwise fine.

Comment: I'm surprised your bothered by "its"/"it's" and you're post doesn't mention any other obvious grammatical errors that most people absolutely hate.

Comment: @Kendra You are a bad, bad person! ;)

Comment: You have my vote !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than coming here to ask for something that's been turned down time and again, just concentrate on getting to 2,000 rep (you're only 350 points away at the time of writing) and you'll be able to correct the "its"/"it's" confusion to your heart's content.

On a more practical note, it's going to be the rare post that only has a single "it's"/"its" mistake in it. There *will* be other things you can correct or expand on.

Comment: Good to know about the 2000 points; looking forward to it.  About offending posts usually having more errors: even when that's the case, often the punctuation is all I'm qualified to fix ;)

Comment: It's not only about typos. I "hate" those code without code formatting. And yes I can change something, but it's VERY annoying to search for comma, colon etc..  also I don't want to change authors intentions. Example? https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/185955/revisions